# How to make a batch file that loops though folders in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch

How can i make a script (like a .bat) that loops though every folder (inside a main folder), gets the folder "Vehicles" (that is present in each one) and copies it to another folder?

[How the folders look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTxEc.png)
[What is present in each folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQpB2.png)

I need to copy the vehicles folder that is present in each of the other folders (note that the content of the vehicles folder is different in each instance) and make it a single folder, that contains all of the files of all of the instances of "vehicles"

(also note that now it only contains 20 folders, but i want to add more folders in the future and just run it again when needed)

Comment: Hello, What have you tried? SuperUser is not a scripting service